# NHibernate and SQL Server 2008 encryption

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sql-server-2008, encryption

How to perform SQL Server built-in encryption/decryption with NHibernate? I mean encryption of separate columns.

Comment: @Dixon.. did you find out how to implement encryption through nhibernate? I am using Fluent NHibernate and specifying the formula in the map function, but the formula query is not being sent to the database. Here is my mapping code. base.Map(x => x.CreditScore).CustomSqlType("VARBINARY(MAX)").Formula( "(open symmetric key customer_value_crypto_key decryption by certificate cim_customer_crypt_cert select encryptbykey(key_guid('customer_value_crypto_key'),credit_score)");

Comment: Can you use a stored procedure to do the decryption reading of the table (OPEN SYMMETRIC / select) and map Hibernate to that store procedure instead of mapping directly to the table?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Sorry, missed your "SQL built-in" mention. This is not SQL built-in, this is NHibernate "integrated".

But could be an option of what you're trying to achieve.

This can be done by using a UserType.

You can find this explained in detail here: http://gustavoringel.blogspot.be/2009/02/encrypting-password-or-other-strings-in.html

And fully implemeted here:
https://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns/UserTypes/EncryptedString.cs?r=65faefa249b695c97787f46f28e6c775a0601533